# Master Page option doesn't exist

Tags: 2010

I'm working on this ShP2010 project, but i don't have the "Master Page" link under "Look and Feel" in my site settings.

Is that a configuration? can it be enabled to show the link?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

follow this steps

Goto Site collection feature

Activate "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure"

Goto Manage site feature

Activate "SharePoint Server Publishing"

Thanks,

Ashish Chotalia

Answer (score 1):

In 2007 I'm pretty sure you had to enable the publishing infrastructure site collection feature and the publishing site feature.  You might have to do the same with 2010.

Comment: This is still true for SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's true in SP2010, but in 2007 you couldn't select a different masterpage in WSS 3.0 via the website, only via Sharepoint Designer (set as default masterpage).
If you are using SPF 2010, this might be the problem you are facing.